# Is it efficient to scan the page for a keyword every second?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, optimization, memory-efficient

So I am working on a personal userscript for myself and a few friends. The userscript is used to block keywords on a page.

To search for the keywords on the page I use:

```
var filter = ["worda", "wordb", "wordc"];
var found = false;

var check =
    function () {
        //Stores the content of the head and body in the document.
        var head = $("head").html();
        var body = $("body").html();


        $.each(filter, function(index, item) {
            if ((head + body).toString().toLowerCase().contains(item.toLowerCase()))  {
                window.clearInterval(interval);
                console.log("Found: " + item);
                found = true;
                return false;
            }
        });

        if (found) {
            $("body").hide();
            var originalTitle = $(document).prop("title");
            $(document).prop("title", "Blocked");

            window.setTimeout(function() {
                if (confirm("This page contains a blocked keyword, are you sure you'd like to continue?")) {
                    $(document).prop("title", originalTitle);
                    $("body").show();
                    return;
                }
            }, 1);
        }
    };
```

And then I set it to repeat every second through:

```
var interval = window.setInterval(check, 1000);
```

The reason I re-check the page every second is because new content may have been dynamically created through Javascript, and I need to make sure that it is also filtered.

However, I'd like to know if this is the most efficient way to scan the page for keywords, or if there is a more efficient method which does not require me to re-check the entire page (possibly only need to re-check new elements).

Also I'd like to push the interval as low as I can (I'm thinking around 100ms), however I do not know if this will be very resource-friendly.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Rather than checking on interval. Try to check it when anything changes.. That will be much more efficient.

Comment: Exactly @mzeus.bolt's suggestion is correct.
Check on some suitable event like keyup or blur to check input field's values to have restricted words.

Comment: Try to check when it is going to submit (as you have `are you sure you'd like to continue?` in your code, so i think it have something to submit?)

Comment: Issue is this is aimed to be an extension that runs on all pages, and needs to scan all new elements created (not just inputs, so using events such as keyup won't work well). Not sure how I would achieve this without an interval.

Comment: @AlivetoDie That dialog is shown when a blocked keyword is detected, and asks the user if they are sure they would like to continue to the website. It's not related to the submission of data.

Comment: @Potato Gun: There surely is some kind of event that gets triggered when the DOM gets rendered or changed, scanning at intervals is not only bas in terms of performance but also very unprecise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're correct that scanning the content of the page periodically is an inefficient approach to the problem. That being said, if it's only running once a second, it probably isn't a huge deal.

Still, there's a better option. The [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) interface can be used to fire events when a document, or a part of a document, is modified. This is perfect for what you're trying to do:

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(function() {
    … scan the document for your keywords …
});
observer.observe(document, {
    childList: true,
    characterData: true,
    subtree: true
});
```

Comment: Hey, not sure if you're familiar with this but I've looked into a jQuery plugin called livequery (https://github.com/brandonaaron/livequery) which I believe simply adds a nice wrapper for the MutationObserver (so I can do something such as `$('body').livequery(function() { ... })`). I think I'll probably go this route, but wanted to know if there's any reason to use just the plain MutationObserver? Thank you.

Comment: @PotatoGun I'm not certain that plugin is going to help you here. From what I can tell, it only triggers when elements are added to or removed from the DOM -- changes to their text won't fire an event.

Comment: Ah yes, I was simply thinking about new elements being added and was not thinking about an elements text being changed. I guess `MutationObserver`s are the way to go. One last question: In the callback function, how do I actually reference the element which triggered the event? @duskwuff

Comment: Or are you suggesting that I use the function in my main post to re-check the entire page when a mutation is triggered?